# What is the Login and Password to install Elementary OS?

Tags: release-odin

**Firstly**, my system components:

- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700F CPU @ 2.90GHz 2.90 GHz
- Installed RAM: 64.0 GB (63.9 GB usable)
- System type: 64-bit operating
  system, x64-based processor
- Graphics Card: MSI GeForce RTX 4090 24GB
  GDRR6X

**Secondly**, the issue is I have been trying to install elementary OS locally on my machine for a week now and whether I use safe mode or does not matter I cannot get past this elementary OS Horus login and password screen and it was not provided to me when I download in the ISO from the website.

I also keep getting this error: **nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (1940000a1)**

Is there a way to solve this? I really don't want to use any other distro of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Enter root mode from `grub` and try to change the password as root. or simply reinstall the OS especially that you didn't install anything yet.

As for NVIDIA. This is a Linux question independent form this question and platform.